# GDB command line interface error: Unrecognized escape character \x in format string

Tags: gdb

I have a small program that can ask users for some input (in essence just the gets function). Now, I want to play around with the input a little bit. I run the program with gdb and I want to insert bytes in hexadecimal format in the gdb prompt.

The way I tried to do it on the gdb command line interface is like so:

```
(gdb) printf "\x20\x20" | ./program
```

But that results in the error:

```
Unrecognized escape character \x in format string.
```

If I do the same in the shell without the gdb prompt its working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong -- it is just a missing feature of gdb.  You could file a bug report.

A workaround is:

```
(gdb) printf "%c", 0x20
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint at the workaround. Kind of glad that I wasn't doing anything wrong this time.